# I18n html markup rendering w/ express-flash

Tags: javascript, node.js, internationalization, server-side, i18n-node

I'm wondering about implementation in a node/express controller of `i18n` segments when they contain html markup. I'm using `express-flash` to output an error message after a post request:

```
i18n.__({phrase: 'flash.my_custom_error_message', locale: req.getLocale()}
```

My output works fine, but if the segment contains HTML markup, it won't be rendered by the browser. It will show:

> `<strong>Error:</strong> My custom error message.`

*instead of:*

> **Error:** My custom error message.

I was assuming there would be a solution similar to how I would do `i18n` implementation in a Pug/Jade template with `#{__('')}` and `!{__('')}` for static strings or expressions/translation segments with HTML markup or links.

Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: I assume this has nothing todo with i18n. How do you output the string?

Comment: I'm using `req.flash('error', { msg: err.message });` on a `.catch(function (err) {});` to output the translation to the client using `express-flash`.

Comment: express-flash does not output anything as i read it. it just populates a `messages.info` variable

Comment: It renders the flash message, which is in this case my translated segment. I wonder if is the `express-flash` package that is not allowing for the html to render.

Comment: can you show how it renders it?

Comment: The flash middleware uses connect-flash and `res.render` to output the response to the client, not sure if that answers your question, but I was assuming it would allow for HTML markup rendering in a `req.flash()` function. Actually, I think need to update my question title to include express-flash to keep it specific to the problem.

Comment: Sry can't help. My guess is, whatever template engine you use to output the message it gets escaped by that. so in other words i asume its not i18n and express-flash but some other code that isn't in your question.